# how do i set font-size for "Tinymce" text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-rails

I am building an application where i used `tinymce-rails` gem.It's a nice text editor i am dealing with.But i am not able to set text's **font size**.Please help me out.

I have the below code in my `tinymce.yml` file:

```
default:
plugins:
- image
- link
alternate:
selector: textarea.table-editor
toolbar: styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | table
plugins:
- table
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `tinymce.yml` and try,

```
setup : function(ed)
{
  ed.on('init', function() 
   {
      this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '50px';
   });
}
```

And change your font size according to your need and it works in tinymca 4.